# setState called from onKeyPress not updating the input text value

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Thanks in advance.

I tried to update a state from **onKeyPress** on text input on react native. The state is actually updating but the value in input text is not changing.

This is working fine in iOS but not in android. Here is my code.

```
<TextInput 
   value={this.state.taskDisplay}
   onKeyPress={this.updateTaskEvent}
   onTextInput={this.updateTask}
   keyboardType={'numeric'}
/>


updateTaskEvent = (e) => { 
       const key = e.nativeEvent.key;  
       if (key == 'Backspace') {
           // make some calculation for a variable **value**
           this.setState({ taskDisplay: value}); 
       }
}
```

When I console the taskDisplay state its working fine(Android and iOS). But in iOS the value in the input field changes but in android it stats as it is.

Am I missing anything in android part!

Any work Arounds!

Comment: Instead of onKeyPress I would rather use the onChangeText prop from TextInput.

Comment: @Arbnor how to Identify the backspace key event in onChangeText

Comment: Could you provide the whole code for the related components? perhaps a code sandbox?

Comment: @dglozano , thanks for reply, FYI, if I log the state it actually updating the state value but the updated value is not displayed in the Input box.
If I hit the backspace the input box works as normal. So am actually overriding the backspace event.

Comment: I see, but if you don't provide a more complete example I believe it will be hard to help you :)

Comment: @AnkitJayaprakash you can use both onKeyPress and onChangeText to fully support the TextInput

Comment: @Arbnor let me try, my main use is to override the actual backspace event. Here if I press the backspace in android, react sets the state correctly but it also triggers the backspace of text input . So It clears the last text. I don't wont that because I wrote a logic to clear text from left to right.

ANY suggestion! This issue happens only in Android, iOS its fine